# Hyndsight's LaTeX template for a CV not working on TeXworks

Tags: templates, cv

I've got [this style](http://robjhyndman.com/research/cv.sty) from [this blog post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/cv/). I'm using TeXworks with the configuration `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX`.

I found on the web a good minimal code that should work. The code is reproduced below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cv}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
 author = {Doe, J. and Dane, D., and Dewy, R.},
 year = {2000},
 title = {This and That},
 journal = {Journal of Deep Understanding of Things},
}

\end{filecontents}


\name{Rob J Hyndman}
\info{Address: & Department of Econometrics \& Business Statistics, Monash University, VIC 3800, Australia.\\
 Phone: & +61 3 9905 2358\\
 Email: & Rob.Hyndman@monash.edu\\
 WWW: & robjhyndman.com}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\addtocategory{papers}{ref1}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{publications}
\printbib{papers}
\end{publications}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that, unlike the sample below, my generated PDF stops at the **Publications** section. That is, it does not contain the subsection **Refereed research paper**.

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to show all the links. The code pasted above is from http://www.rqna.net/qna/prytri-cv-template-having-issues-with-biblatex.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cv.sty` has this on line 66:

```
\usepackage[sorting=ynt,bibstyle=authoryear-comp,defernumbers=true,maxnames=20,firstinits=true, uniquename=init,dashed=false,doi=false,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

Hence you have to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`. The compilation would be

```
pdflatex → biber → pdflatex
```

Then you get:

[image]